# Json Web Token por mas de 1 hora

Tags: c#, rest, jwt, webapi

Se necesita exponer 3 consultas a una base de datos via rest/api y hacer que cuando se consulte (la consulta es otro webservice / cliente que realiza la consulta) se tenga un token de autenticación el servicio se necesita 24/7 consultando; pero teniendo la seguridad integrada por que se necesita muy buena seguridad.

Se realizo una clase para definir las propiedades de modelo de dato del jwt;
se indica que el token expire cada 7 días:

```
    public class JWTContainerModel
    {
      public int ExpireMinutes { get; set; } = 10080; // 7 dias

      public string SecretKey { get; set; } 

      public string SecurityAlgorithm { get; set; } 

      public Claim[] Claims { get; set; }
     }
```

pero Según algunos foros lo ideal es que el token expire cada hora, MI Conocimiento en JWT es de novato. quisiera saber si es posible hacerse por este medio o por otra tecnología de autenticación, al requerimiento.

Comment: Lo ideal es que en cada llamada el token se regenere, ahora para la expiracion se puede modificar el parametro de expiracion, pero tambien debes averiguar como se valida ese token del lado del servidor ya que es alli donde se puede agregar o suprimir las reglas de autenticacion y autorizacion. Una prueba sencilla de ver tus parametros es usando la pagina https://jwt.io/ alli puedes pegar tu token para que veas como esta conformatdo.

Comment: @MiguelZarate si en un ambiente cliente que utiliza un browser para autenticarse es lo ideal pero el cliente es un web service y no se puede generar constantemente los tokens que otra opción sugeririras? así sea no utilizar jwt

Comment: Tu pregunta tal como está planteada se puede basar en opiniones. La respuesta directa al título de tu pregunta es que puedes definir el tiempo de expiración a gusto: bien sea 1 segundo o algunos años. Ahora, la pregunta es, ¿necesitas realmente un token que expira? JWT es un estándar para ser usado por lo general en escenarios [SSO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Sign-On). Pero luego mencionas: *el cliente es un webservice y no se puede generar constantemente los tokens*. Creo que deberías aclarar mejor tu problema, por favor has clic en [edit] y agrega todos los detalles posibles.

Comment: Aun te falta definir el comportamiento de sesion ok el token expira cada hora que haras despues regenerar el token automaticamente o le pides al usuario que se vuelva a logear, lo mas comun es que despues de un cierto tiempo de inactividad la sesion se cierre, eso lo puedes manejar con tablas y reglas de negocio. Entonces antes de implementar debes tener claras tu reglas de sesion para que en base a eso decidas sobre que te sera mas util para el manejo de sesion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque tu cliente sea un WebService, eso no es impedimento para utilizar **JWT**. Lo que debes hacer es **establecer un tiempo de vida** (el que consideres oportuno, no tiene por que ser 1 hora) y **comprobar la validez** en cada llamada.

Aún así, lo más importante es que sepas como funciona la tecnología JWT, y como integrarla en un Web API de ASP.NET, **antes de realizar tu proyecto**.

Te recomiendo algunos artículos interesantes:

[JSON Web Token - Seguridad en servicios Web API 2 de ASP.NET](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/6/17/json-web-token-seguridad-en-servicios-web-api-2-de-aspnet)

[JSON Web Token - Seguridad en servicios Web API de .NET Core](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/5/20/json-web-token-seguridad-en-servicios-web-api-de-net-core)

[Cómo crear un cliente C# para un Web API de ASP.NET Core (I)](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/8/21/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-cliente-c-para-un-web-api-de-aspnet-core-i)

[Cómo crear un cliente C# para un Web API de ASP.NET Core (II)](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/9/9/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-cliente-c-para-un-web-api-de-aspnet-core-ii)